# For a maven project in eclipse can I configure menu option Project/Clean to invoke mvn clean

Tags: eclipse, maven

Is there some kind of way of binding an external build command to the eclipse clean action?

If it helps, I am using :

- Apache Maven 2.2.1
- Eclipse Galileo 3.5
- M2Eclipse plugin (which I know offers an option to run mvn clean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Project Properties -> Maven -> Lifecycle Mapping you can configure which goals to run AFTER a clean s involed on this project

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can wire any external tool, to be invoked during a particular build lifecycle event by going to Project Properties -> Builders page. There you will be able to define a new tool and specify when it should run.