# Can't find maven eclipse builder

Tags: eclipse, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, m2e

I am using (STS) springsource tools suite which is eclipse... with maven plugin...

this post:

[Invoke "Maven Project Builder" in Eclipse on Run As -> Android Application (or manually)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726564/invoke-maven-project-builder-in-eclipse-on-run-as-android-application-or-m)

suggests that there should be a maven builder in my project builders... now I cannot find it in the add menu ...

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the problem is that STS uses an old un-maintained version of the maven plugin... The new versions are supposed to have fixed that and moved to new versions...

I didn't try it yet, but that is supposed to solve it.